# Why does jsDoc not parse my comment that has no trailing code?

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I added a new plugin to jsdoc, introducing a new tag:

```js
dictionary.defineTag("newtag", {
  mustHaveValue: false,
  canHaveType: false,
  canHaveName: true,
  onTagged: function(doclet, tag) {
    doclet.newtag = tag.value;
    doclet.kind = "newitem";
  }
});
```

But jsDoc seems to only create a new doclet when the comment is followed by some javascript code. This works:

```js
/**
 * @newtag name
 */
somename = function(){};
```

But this does not get recognized:

```
/**
 * @newtag name
 */
```

The native jsDoc tag @module does not require trailing code either so it should definately somehow be possible to add comments without code. But why does it not work in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsDoc allows you to document arbitrary things without trailing code if you provide everything it needs to do so. For instance, here is a module file named 'foo.js' with no code that documents a member:

```
/**
 * @module Foo
 */

/**
 * A named member of Foo.
 *
 * @name Bar
 * @type {String} 
 * @memberof Foo
 */
```

which will produce the following result (assuming a very simple output template):

```
Foo

Members

(static) Bar :String
| Source: foo.js, line 5

A named member of Foo.
```

By default, when JsDoc parses your source code, it connects a JsDoc comment (internally referred to as a 'doclet') with the feature following it in your source code.

If you do not provide a name in the doclet, JsDoc uses the source to discover a value for the `@name` tag, as in:

```
/**
 * A useless string constant.
 * @type {String}
 */
const Bar = 'useless';
```

To create a doclet without attaching it to any trailing code, you simply need to assign a name so JsDoc doesn't need to figure it out for itself.